# Call and dial numbers on Android

Tags: android, time, phone-call

I want to program an app to make my life easier. Each time when I go to my work, I have to go to a phone, call a number and press some numbers and give my work id and function to book/ register my time at work.

So now I want to make a little app with some buttons to register and deregister. I want to push the button and make a call in the background and emulate dialing my id and function.

I found out how to make a call:
http://www.mkyong.com/android/how-to-make-a-phone-call-in-android/

But I didn't find out how to put this into the background and make the app pretend dialing.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be simpler to place the numbers in your Contact list?  Then create a widget for each.  I do the same thing to automatically enter the password when I check my voicemail.  See: http://www.androidcentral.com/adding-pauses-contacts-dialing-extensions

Comment: I didn't know that you can use pauses, that's amazing! I'll have a look if it is possible to hardcode these pauses or save the numbers into my contactlist and load them via app :)
I'm not really sure now, because if the app works, I'd like to share it with my coworkers

Comment: As shown in the link, the contact number would simply be the string of numbers you'd type, with commas in place to delay the next series of numbers while the automated system does it's thing. For what it's worth, I don't think it's possible to have Android dial a call from the background.  Once you activate the dialer, it's going to take focus.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a developer Q&A site, but have you looked at Tasker?  Very robust.  Very thorough.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm

Comment: Well this app looks really cool, but I'd like to make my own app, to get better developing android apps :)

Comment: +1 agree whole heartedly.  Just wanted to point you to something that will do what you ask and much, much more (almost to a fault ;))